# Allow multiple buttons to be pressed simultaneously via multitouch in QT

Tags: qt, multi-touch

I’m looking to allow multiple buttons to be pressed at the same time when using a multi touch device for an application developed in QT for ios/android etc

I cannot for the life of me see how to do this.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Qt's stock buttons use `MouseArea`, which doesn't support multi touch, amongst other things.

Use `MultiPointTouchArea` instead to implement your own multi-touch friendly buttons.